# "А так — да, ..." или "А так, да — ..."

Tags: пунктуация

Вопрос по пунктуации. Рассмотрим короткий диалог:

> — Впредь нужно ориентироваться на анонсы трансляций?
>   — Сегодня будет трансляция в первом зале. А так — да,
>   ориентируйтесь на анонсы.

Как правильно ставить тире и запятую:

> А так — да, ...

или

> А так, да — ...

?

И почему? Интересно именно обосновать теоретически.

Интуитивно первый вариант нравится больше, но обосновать не могу.

**UPD:** Точнее, даже так: второй вариант мне кажется явно неправильным, но обосновать это у меня не получается. Буду признателен, если кто-то поможет разобраться.

Comment: Я тоже выбрал бы первый вариант.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Краткий ответ: в вашем примере верно поставить тире, а не запятую.

Теперь я попробую объяснить, почему.

Ваш пример содержит *эллипсис*, то есть пропуск одного или нескольких элементов в предложении, которые восстанавливаются по контексту. Это явление с трудом может быть описано в рамках грамматики зависимостей (примерно то, чему учат в русских школах) или грамматики составляющих (примерно то, о чем писал Хомский), и я могу лишь на пальцах объяснить, что здесь происходит.

Рассмотрим пример:

> — Впредь нужно ориентироваться на анонсы трансляций?
>   — Сегодня будет трансляция в первом зале. А так — да, ориентируйтесь на анонсы.

В примере есть вопрос и ответ. Ответ состоит из двух предложений с одинаковой структурой, но во втором предложении опущено сказуемое и подлежащее. Оба предложения состоят из трёх частей, первая - это обстоятельство времени, уточняющее, к какому периоду времени относится трансляция (*сегодня*), вторая часть - это сказуемое и подлежащее (*будет трансляция*), и третья часть - обстоятельство места, отвечающее на вопрос, в каком месте будет проходить трансляция (*в первом зале*).

Однако, во втором предложении обстоятельство места заменено целым новым предложением, которое не описывает место проведения трансляций, а дает указание насчет того, где эту информацию можно найти - в анонсах.

Можно также подчеркнуть, что порядок компонетов в обоих предложениях одинаков: сначала идет обстоятельство времени, потом сказуемое и подлежащее, а в конце - обстоятельство места.

Второе предложение с трудом укладывается в рамки письменной речи, для которой, собственно, и созданы правила пунктуции, но тем не менее есть правило, которое в данном случае подходит лучше всего. [Вот оно в справочнике Розенталя](http://rosental.virtbox.ru/punct_xxi.html#sect80.1). Коротко говоря, правило сводится к тому, что эллиптические предложения содержат тире вместо пропущенной части. Поэтому в вашем примере вместо подлежащего и сказуемого *трансляция будет* должно стоять тире.

Теперь насчет запятой. Почему верно поставить запятую после *да*? В примере фраза *да, ориентируйтесь на анонсы* является не только заменителем обстоятельства места, но еще и ответом на вопрос *Впредь нужно ориентироваться на анонсы трансляций?*. Здесь *ориентируйтесь на ананосы* -- это более развернутый ответ, раскрывающий смысл *да*. Поэтому я считаю, что *да* и *ориентируйтесь на анонсы* составляют единое предложение. [Согласно этому правилу](http://rosental.virtbox.ru/punct_xxvi.html#sect103), *да* должно быть отделено запятой, если оно входит в состав большего предложения.

Comment: Ольга, спасибо за развернутый ответ, но, честно говоря, непонятно следующее. Вы говорите: "_в вашем примере верно поставить тире, а не запятую_". Но в обоих моих вариантах есть и тире, и запятая: "_А так — да, ..._" или "_А так, да — ..._". И, согласно правилу из справочника Розенталя, тире может служить заменой пропущенной части как в первом варианте, так и во втором. Так ведь?

Comment: Я дополнила свой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь, вроде бы, все ясно. Как только система позволит, подарю вам `+50` (этого нельзя сделать раньше, чем через сутки после объявления подарка)

Comment: Не торопитесь, может, придет человек, который занимался эллипсисом и знает лучше.

Answer (score 0):

"А так - да..." - это простонародный вариант "А в этом случае - да, ...(и расшифровка - как должны обстоять дела)".
Думаю, тут подойдет вариант постановки тире, когда "вторая часть содержит следствие, результат, вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой", а вообще возможностей поставить тире очень много.

Кто не понял, многоточие автор вопроса употребил, чтобы показать, что у предложения есть продолжение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но "`А так - да, ...`" - это отнюдь не аналог "`А в этом случае - да, ...`". Попробуйте подставить ваше "`А в этом случае - да, ...`" в приведенный мною диалог - ерунда получается. В этом диалоге его можно, скорее, заменить на "`А вообще - да, ...`". Ну и, опять-таки, непонятно, как же правильно ставить тире. "*вторая часть содержит следствие, результат, вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой*" - это можно подвести под оба варианта постановки тире.

Answer (score -6):

Вообще не должно быть ни тире, ни, тем более, дефиса. Только многоточие.

> § 185. Многоточие ставится для обозначения незаконченности
>   высказывания, причем знаки вопросительный и восклицательный, если они
>   требуются характером предложения, сохраняются перед многоточием,
>   например:
>
> ```
> Простите, государь!.. Стоять я не могу... Мои колени слабеют...
> Душно... Душно... Где ключи? Ключи, ключи мои!..
> Пушкин
>
> Не правда ль, ты одна?.. Ты плачешь? Я спокоен... Но если...
> Пушкин
>
> Не мешает сделать замечание, что Манилова... но, признаюсь, о дамах я очень боюсь говорить, да притом мне пора возвратиться к нашим
> ```
>
> героям.
>       Гоголь
>
> § 186. Многоточие ставится для обозначения заминок в речи, в том числе
>   и внутри слова, например:
>
> ```
> Мама, ты не входи ко мне, а только подойди к двери. Вот что... Третьего дня я заразился в больнице дифтеритом и теперь... мне
> ```
>
> нехорошо.
>       Чехов
>
> ```
> ...Ва... ва... ва... ваше превосходительство, – шептал Попов.
> А. К. Толстой
> ```

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=mnogo

Comment: Please source your claim.

Comment: That's basic knkowledge of Russian. Начальная школа, if you have been unafare of the fact.

Comment: (sighs) nevermind.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the speakers confidence in what she says? If the speaker is not sure, then three dots, if the speaker is sure, then a dash.

Comment: It depends on incompleteness in saying (§ 185). One mightalso say with a perfect confidence 'более лучше', which doesn't make the saying more grammatical.

Comment: We're speaking here about the standard grammar, don't we? In this standard grammar the punctuation serves as a means to express one's emotions and the attitude to what one says, doesn't it? So why use 3 dots, if the speaker is sure about what he is saying?